# How to save a Keras model in the CNTK format

Tags: keras, cntk

Is there a way to save a Keras model to the format of CNTK so that we can load it by using CNTK's API?

I have tried this code below but it failed:

```
a = Input(shape=(224,224,3))
b = Conv2D(64, (2,2), name='conv1')(a)
model = Model(inputs=a, outputs=b)
cntk.combine(model.outputs).save('model2.dnn')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keras-CNTK saving model-v2 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394213/keras-cntk-saving-model-v2-format)

Answer (score 3):

Please see [Keras-CNTK saving model-v2 format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394213/keras-cntk-saving-model-v2-format)

To save Keras model in CNTK format (when using CNTK as back end):

```
import cntk as C
from keras.backend import load_model

keras_model = load_model('my_keras_model.h5')

cntk.combine(keras_model.model.outputs).save('my_cntk_model')
cntk_model = C.load_model('my_cntk_model')
```

To save Keras in TensorFlow format (when using TensorFlow as backend):

```
model = load_model('model2.h5')
sess = K.get_session()
tf_saver = tf.train.Saver()
tf_saver.save(sess=sess, save_path=checkpoint_path)
```

Comment: Yes. I can saved the model. But when I tried to load the saved model file, it report an error: `raise ValueError('Cannot load a model that is neither a file nor a byte buffer.') RuntimeError: SWIG director method error`

Answer (score 0):

After your code, try this:

`loaded_model = cntk.load('model2.dnn')`

You will find more details [here](https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.ops.functions.html#cntk.ops.functions.Function.load).

Answer (score 0):

I use this [converter](https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn) to convert models between keras and CNTK.

1. Save keras model `model.save('keras_model.h5')`
2. Install converter `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn.git@master`
3. Run command: `mmconvert -sf keras -iw keras_model.h5 -df cntk -om cntk_model.dnn`

Comment: this is not an answer but a comment